# Porque meu Banco de Dados ( Sugar ) retorna null quando busco por id?

Tags: android, sqlite

Eu salvo no meu banco usando sugar toda vez que recebo uma nova notificação, funciona corretamente, depois em um fragment eu populo um recycleview com todas as notificações do banco de dados, tambem funciona corretamente, mas agora quando eu tento deletar do banco por id eu não consigo, o meu banco de dados retorna null pra alguns ids ( veja a imagem do debug), já tentei entender mas não to conseguindo perceber o porque.

Código de adição no banco:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        SugarContext.init( this );
        Log.d("igr", "Mensagem Recebida");
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d("igr", "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            String titulo = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String mensagem = remoteMessage.getData().get("text");

            try{
                Notificacao notificacao= new Notificacao(titulo,mensagem);
                SugarRecord.save(notificacao);
                SugarContext.terminate();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("igr", "Erro ao salvar notificacao no DB: " + e);
                SugarContext.terminate();
            }
```

Meu modelo:

```
package br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal.DataBase;

import com.orm.dsl.Table;

/**
 * Created by igord on 03/07/2017.
 */

@Table
public class Notificacao {

    private Long id;
    private String titulo;
    private String texto;


    public Notificacao(){

    }

    public Notificacao(String titulo, String texto) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    /* gets e sets */

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca ouvi falar desse Sugar, mas pela documentação do mesmo, acredito que você deveria buscar o objeto para deletar dessa forma (porque está usando a notação `@Table` na criação do Modelo) :

```
Notificacao notificacao = Notificacao.findById(Notificacao.class,positionToDelete);
```

Dê uma olhada:
https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Ta certo do jeito que estou usando, já usei sem usar @table e estava dando o mesmo erro, o problema é que depende muito do ID, alguns ele deleta, outros não .. isso que não estou entendendo

Comment: Sinceramente, tenta implementar a base usando as classes nativas: SQLiteOpenHelper e SQLiteDatabase. Na minha opinião, tem muito mais controle fazendo dessa forma.

Comment: Vou tentar isso, queria usar o sugar pq o banco é extremamente simples

Comment: O problema dessas soluções "simples" é a complexidade para resolver os problemas, rs

Comment: refiz em Sqlite mas ta dando erro ainda :/ https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218926/porque-meu-delete-do-sqlite-diz-que-deletou-mas-n%C3%A3o-deletou